# C# code to Python with COM interface - casting issue

Tags: c#, python, casting, com, comtypes

I have trouble to convert comtype in the needed objects. I get a working C# sample and must convert it into python Code. I use ComTypes for that.

The detailed Problem:
The Object Hirachy is the following(from the CANoe documentation):

```
System  
  +Namespaces:Namespaces (collection)  
Namespaces  
  +Count
  +Item:Namespace
Namespace  
  +Name  
  +Variables  
  +Namespaces:Namespaces
```

Python code:

```py
App = CreateObject('CANoe.Application') 
mNamespaces = App.System.Namespaces #oNamespaces = POINTER(INamespaces2)                       
mNamespace = mNamespaces.Item(3) #mNamespace = POINTER(INamespace), I have the Right object with a wrong interface. mNamespace had the right namespace object (_Statistics)
mStatisticsNamespaces = ? #here
```

C# excample Code to Transfer:

```cs
mSystem = (CANoe.System)mApplication.System;
mNamespaces = (CANoe.Namespaces)mSystem.Namespaces;
mNamespace = (CANoe.Namespace)mNamespaces["_Statistics"];
mStatisticsNamespaces = (CANoe.Namespaces)mNamespace.Namespaces;
mNamespaceCAN1 = (CANoe.Namespace)mStatisticsNamespaces["CAN1"];
mVariables = (CANoe.Variables)mNamespaceCAN1.Variables;
mVariable = (CANoe.Variable)mVariables["Busload"];
```

The mNamespace object contains now the Methods
mNamespace
    +Name
    +Variables

[VisualStudio Variable view of mNamespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4leCe.png)
[VisualStudio Variable view of mNamespaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNKNB.png)

It seams I must convert the mNamespace object like the C# sample. But I don't have an Idea how I can make it.
I had in Python no includes like c++/C# so I can't write like the C# sample.

Had anyone an Idee how to manage this?

Thanks

Comment: While this seems to have nothing to do with c# as a question other than you have an example in c#.. have you tried something like `App = CANoe.Namespaces(CreateObject('CANoe.Application')` -- note, I dont do python but this seems to be how you force types looking at the help pages.

Comment: Hi, in this case the Name CANoe is undefiened. I see the GetModule function, to create objects from dlls, but this module is completely isolated from the other generates.